# Approaches for distributed implementation of C++ application (tree structure)

Tags: java, c++, design-patterns, tree, distributed

I have to make an existing C++ application distributed and scalable. I am looking for practical advice for a good approach (distributed patterns, frameworks, etc.) how to do it. I have ideas, but I'm not sure about their feasibility.

The existing application's abstract functionality is relatively general:

- the problem has an unbalanced tree form, on each vertex computations
  with non-trivial time have to be done (the computations become more
  complex further down the tree), some vertices fork
- the tree's form is not known in advance, the tree exploration and the computation are done on-the-fly
- the order in which the tree is explored is important (DFS is okay, but should be customizable)
- the vertices can be explored independent of each other, but locality is important because of caching (i.e. a branch should be explored by the same processing unit)
- global statistics have to be collected during the run
- the functionality is similar to state space exploration. The program is relatively complex, but the core is just a loop

Very vaguely put, I have an overabundance of mostly independent tasks that have to be assigned to a smaller number of processing units, while considering locality (child tasks should go to processor of parent, grandparent, etc. task).

The requirements for the distributed implementation are:

- for now the target is 50-150 machines, but potentially should be able to scale well for up to 1000s of nodes
- persistence of the state space (especially with all data) is not important, but would be nice

The straightforward way is to implement the communication, partitioning, load balancing, etc. manually using ZeroMQ, NanoMSG or some other messaging library (or even MPI). This is what I don't want to do, because it takes a lot of time, is error-prone and I would probably end up implementing many things that already exist.

I thought of using a Pregel-like graph processing systems (Giraph, GraphX, GraphLab), but they are not designed for dynamic graph building, but rather for executing computation on existing graphs.

Then I thought that I could use Apache Spark or maybe Hama (this would actually be a quite interesting approach). But here my issue is that the original application is in C++ (and is relatively large and complex), but Spark has no C/C++ API. I have never written multi-language code and don't know too much about JNI/JNA/BridJ/SWIG, and I'm not sure how much work this would be and how big the performance overhead would be. Or if it feasible at all.

That's why I would like to ask the community, especially people with experience in distributed programming:
Which approach (above mentioned ones, or new ones) is feasible and good for such a problem, both in terms of patterns (BSP, DAG execution, simple master-worker, etc.) and specific tools (Giraph, Spark, messaging libs, etc.)?
How about the Java-C++ interaction if I decide to go with a JVM-based framework?
Any other comments or advice?

Thank you very much!